# Unable to render links on page using DreamWeaver Templating

Tags: tridion-2011

We are using the following line of code in our DreamWeaver Template to resolve a link in Tridion. But,not getting the desired output, the link is not being resolved on the page. Is there anything wrong with the code? Please help..

```
<a href="@@internal@@" tridion:href="@@internal@@" title="@@title@@" target="_blank">@@title@@</a>  


<a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@" href="dummy.html" class="intro-link"><h2>@@RenderComponentField  ("title_intro", 0)@@</h2></a>
```

Comment: Can you add some more info as to "what is the expected result"? Are you publishing these? Do you have the "Resolve Links" TBB in your template? Also consider posting this question in the Tridion Q&A site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Comment: The "title_intro" field should be rendered as a hyperlink instead its just a plain text on the page. Yes we are publishing these. The "Resolve Links" TBB has been added as well.

Comment: That usually means that the target component is not published.

Comment: The page containing the component has been published.

Answer (score 0):

You Publication Target Language may be set to none - It should be set to the appropriate Server Site Language (JSP, ASP.NET, TCDL etc).

If that does not solve the problem - please post the published output (not the rendered browser view, but the actual output in your page file or broker DB entry).

Comment: Publication Target Language has been set to ASP.NET. 
The following is the output obtained by previewing the page.                                                                                                                <a href="/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/Preview/Preview.aspx#id=tcm:15-287"  class=&quot;intro-link&quot;><h2><span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title_intro[1]"} -->Cancer Insurance</span></h2></a>

Comment: Not the preview - the actual published result. You should have something like `<tridion:ComponentLink ComponentUri="tcm:1-23" />` etc

Comment: The actual result looks like this in our case                                                                                                                                        <h2><span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title_intro[1]"} -->Critical Illness</span></h2>

Comment: Is this as seen in the browser, or as written to the file system? You need to check the file in the File System. If this is what you're seeing in the actual file, then your target is not set up to ASP.NET

Comment: The actual published result looks something like this in the File System -
<tridion:ComponentLink ComponentUri="tcm:1-23" /> 

The target is also set up to ASP.NET. But, in the final page we are getting this output : 
<h2><span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title_intro[1]"} -->Critical Illness</span></h2>

Comment: Your link code seems to be being executed (otherwise you would be seeing the tridion:ComponentLink.../> in your browser). So I can only assume that the Component tcm:1-23 is not on a page anywhere using a Component Template which has a priority higher than Never Link.

If you are ceratain it is published on a page with an appropriate template, your next step will be to validate your cd_link_conf.xml and compare the cd_storage_conf.xml files in your deployer and your web application. They should have the same settings in them.

If that fails, try looking at your debug log files.

Comment: Everything under the "Publication" node in the cd_link_conf.xml has been commented out in the web application and only license file has been mentioned. Is that a reason for the Component links not resolving in the browser?

Comment: Please update your question to include your cd_storage_conf.xml, cd_link_conf.xml -